# A conjecture about number 641

Tags: number-theory

I conjecture that $233\#-1$ is the only number of the form $p\#-1$, where p is a prime and # denotes the primorial function, which is divisibile by $641$. $641$ is the smallest prime dividing $F_5$, as shown by Euler.

Comment: @Peter could you disproof the conjecture?

Comment: The only thing I see about $641$ is that it's prime and it's a factor of $F5$, the 5th Fermat's number. If that's the case, I am not really sure why this type of conjecture should be unique to $641$, if it is indeed true.

Comment: @Mann can you find another prime p such that p#-1 is divisibile by 641?

Comment: No, what I mean is. What is unique about the conjecture $p' \# - 1$ divisible by some prime $p_{0}$. If it's for $641$, can't I take some other values? What makes you think $641$ and $233$ are unique? This could help us proceed.

Answer (score 3):

It is true, but I doubt there's any significance to it. The number $p\# - 1$ is clearly not divisible by $641$ if $p\geq 641$, and it turns out that $233\# \equiv 1\pmod{641}$. Similarly, $3\#1 - 1 = 5$ is divisible by $5$; and $7\#-1 = 209$ is divisible by $11$ and $19$; and etc.